# How can I power a PC-fan with mains power?

Tags: power-electronics, mains, wiring, fan

I am making a project where I want to integrate an old fan I have laying around.  I want to plug it into a socket and start.

In my first try connected the red and black from the converter with the socket, pluged it in and the reaction from the fuse told me I was wrong.

Do I just need to connect brown to brown, blue to blue, and red and black with red and black from the fan?

Both fan and converter are 12V.

I know I could just try, but I am scared to break something bigger than my little project.

[image]

Comment: *connected the red and black from the converter with the socket,* You plugged in the low-voltage (DC) side (DC: because black and red are the canonical colors for negative and positive leads of a DC supply) of your switch-mode supply into your grid-voltage AC outlet. To little surprise, that destroyed it and effectively shorted your outlet, triggering your fuse. You hence have produced e-waste, and can be happy you did not get hurt.

Comment: Anyways, this is a electronics *usage* question without sufficient engineering aspects to it; I'm afraid that's off-topic here.

Comment: You'll likely not get much for responses because what you are trying is inherently dangerous to you and property.  However, I fully appreciate the curiosity and initiative.  Please try to acquire a mentor to help you to explore your endeavors in a safe and beneficial manner.  In general, with European wiring, Brown is AC Line Voltage, Blue is Neutral.  The DC output of your adapter is likely Red and black, with Red being +DC voltage (who's value is printed as 'Output' on your adapter), and black as DC- (typically considered, or tied to, 0V).  However, the DC adapter is probably now broken.

Comment: `I know I could just try` ... not when you can be killed by one part of the circuit

Comment: It’s dead Jim. Get yourself a mains voltage fan or a new power supply.

Comment: it is standard. yellow is the colour used for +12VDC inside PCs

Comment: Maybe look at the manual of the converter before plugging wires anywhere and don’t work with mains voltage if you have no idea how to handle it. You could have easily died there

Answer (score 5):

So initially I didn't read your question closely enough, and missed this part:

> In my first try connected the red and black from the converter with the socket, pluged it in and the reaction from the fuse told me I was wrong.

If you are saying that you plugged the red and black wires from the converter into the mains, then you will have undoubtedly destroyed the converter. Did you really do this?

Similarly if you plugged the red/black wires from the fan into the mains, you'll have destroyed the fan.

---

Assuming you haven't destroyed your DC-DC or fan as discussed above, then:

> Do I just need to connect brown to brown, blue to blue, and red and black with red and black from the fan?

Is most likely correct. Check the datasheet for the DC-DC converter to be sure of the pinout. You can't always trust wire colours, but the presence of brown/blue and the EU socket is highly indicative of standard unified EU mains AC wire colours.

Indeed from the datasheet of the [Meanwell APV-8-12](https://www.meanwell-web.com/content/files/pdfs/productPdfs/MW/APV-8/APV-8-spec.pdf), we have the following diagram which indeed shows that red/black are +12V and GND respectively and so go to the fan. Also brown/blue are indeed the AC Live/Neutral and match the colours of your mains plug:

[image: Device wiring from datasheet]

If the fan is from an ATX standard computer, then simply applying +12V/GND DC to the correct wires should be sufficient to spin it up.

**Be extremely careful** with such wiring as mains can be lethal and a great source of fiery doom. You would be **much safer** buying a plug-in regulated 12V DC supply (e.g. wall-wart style) rather than wiring things up yourself. If wiring up using choc-block as you show, make sure there are no frayed wires, that the choc-block is rated for the voltage/current requirements, and that you insulate any exposed part of the choc-block once done (e.g. in plastic housing, or use a proper junction box/inline connector).

---

However in your case, if it is using the standard pinout seen on PC fans on it's 3-pin connector, then it seems to have non-typical wire colours. The central pin in the standard pinout is the +12V supply, which in your case appears to be the **yellow wire** not the red wire.

The black wire ought to be GND, but again from the blurry image this appears to be at the wrong end for an ATX standard fan.

If the fan is a non-ATX PC fan then without a datasheet it's impossible to say what you need to do. There are some fans which won't spin up unless there is a pulse signal applied to the third wire. Again without the datasheet for the fan who knows if this is the case.

Comment: thanks for the response, you say that is is PROBABLY broken, would it be harmfull if i try to reuse it, but now propperly, or is this just uselessly dangerous?

Comment: @Rubinschwein47 connecting the output to the mains will have destroyed it. Trying to wire it up again won't acheive anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: Black and yellow from the fan go to black and red from the 12V supply.

Inside a PC yellow is +12V and black is 0V (also called ground)
on your AC to DC converter red is the positive output and black the negative.